# Vertical Sub List in Horizontal List Giving Alignment Problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am facing a problem in creating a dropdown menu with images.
I am trying to achieve a center aligned horizontal list with main menu items and corresponding vertical menus.

This is my CSS Code code:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 88px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    min-width: 800px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 0px;
}

#nav > ul {
    padding: 0;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

#nav >ul> li> ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav> ul >li >ul> li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

JQuery Code:

```
$("#nav img").mouseover(function () {
  //$('ul .subList').hide();            
  var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
  var tempSrc = imgSrc.split(".png");
  var newSrc = tempSrc[0] + "Hover.png";
  $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
  $(this).closest('li').children('ul .subList').slideToggle();
});
```

Where nav is the div which contains the list. All the list items are images.

I want the main menu items to be aligned and the sub menu items to be displayed below the corresponding menu but the main menu item is going upwards.

Eg:

Should be: (Desired)

Item1 Item2
Sub1a 
Sub1b

Becomes: (Current output)

Item1 
Sub1a
Sub1b Item2

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle of this? Kinda hard to visualise this :-)

Comment: Thanks Christian for the tip. Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rutagupta/PRGhj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, surprisingly easy fix this actually. It is one of these weird default things that happen with CSS.

To your `#NAV > UL > LI`

Add: `vertical-align: top`

You should always add vertical-align: top to inline-block elements, unless you wish for the opposite effect :-)